# Is there a better or more elegant way to conditionally render different components in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to create an app with a custom navbar, that jumps between pages when you click links.

Here is an abbreviated version of my code:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dicePage: true,
      itemsPage: false
    }
  }

  dicePress = () => {
        this.setState({
          dicePage: true,
          itemsPage: false
        })
  }
  itemsPress = () => {
        this.setState({
          dicePage: false,
          itemsPage: true
        })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={backgroundTile} style={styles.bgImage}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
              <Image source={require('./assets/images/Logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />
            </View>
            {this.state.dicePage && <DicePage />}
            {this.state.itemsPage && <ItemsPage />}
            
            
            <NavBar value='Dice' dicePress={this.dicePress} itemsPress={this.itemsPress} />
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>    
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and

```
class NavBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.bottomNav}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.dicePress}>
                    <Text key='dice' style={styles.nav}>Dice</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.itemsPress}>
                    <Text key='items' style={styles.nav}>Items</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default NavBar;
```

So this works when I test the app - and I'm going to have 4 or 5 pages, so want more options than a ternary operator etc. - but I think there's probably a better or more elegant way to do this.

I've tried React Navigator and other things but am really looking for the absolute simplest way to achieve this (hopefully with DRY coding, as the repetition feels wrong to me). Should I be mapping links *and* functions for this? I don't think I've ever mapped functions before and realise that there probably should be a single adaptable function that would work for all.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Approach

You could make a `pages` object where each key is an identifier for a page and where each corresponding value is the component that represents a page:

```
const pages = {
  dicePage: DicePage,
  itemsPage: ItemsPage
};
```

This way we can decide what should be rendered based on the key only, and all navigation can links can share the same `onPress` handler.

`App.js`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPage: "dicePage" // Default page
    };
  }

  pagePress = (pageName) => {
    this.setState({ currentPage: pageName });
  };

  render() {
    const Page = pages[this.state.currentPage]; // What page should be rendered (based on the `currentPage` key)
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Page />
          <NavBar value="Dice" pagePress={this.pagePress} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

`Navbar.js`

```
class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.pagePress("dicePage")}>
          <Text key="dice">Dice</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.pagePress("itemsPage")}>
          <Text key="items">Items</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

So if you want to expand this with more pages you only need to add key value pairs to the `pages` object and links to your `Navbar`.

*I've removed some things like styling and images to simplify the example.*

#### Second Approach

```
const pages = [
  { key: "dicePage", page: DicePage, pageLinkName: "Dice" },
  { key: "itemsPage", page: ItemsPage, pageLinkName: "Items" },
];

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {pages.map((page) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.props.pagePress(page.key)}
              key={page.key}
            >
              <Text>{page.pageLinkName}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPage: "dicePage", // Default page
    };
  }

  pagePress = (pageName) => {
    this.setState({ currentPage: pageName });
  };

  render() {
    const Page = pages.filter((page) => page.key === this.state.currentPage)[0]
      .page;
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Page />
          <NavBar value="Dice" pagePress={this.pagePress} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Largely the same approach, but structure of `pages` has changed where you now also don't need to manually add new links, but you only need to add new objects to `pages`, which is now an array.