# Page movement by React and Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My idea is that `<LandingPage>` has `<Top>` and it is altered by user clicking progress.

`<Top>` has `pageState`, then it is changed by button clicking in `First` and `Second` page

Is it correct practice? and How can I change the `pageState` of `Top` by clicking the button in `First` and `Second` page ??

These are what I made so far

```
export default function LandingPage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        <Header></Header>    
        <Top></Top>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    );
  
}

const Top = (props) =>{
  const [pageState, setPageState] = useState([]);
  if (pageState == 1){
    return (
      <Second></Second>
    )
  }
  elif (pageState == 2){
    return (
      <Third></Third>
    )
  }
  else {
    return (
      <First></First>
    );
  }
}

const First = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (

      <Button size="lg" color="success" style={{margin:"50px"}} onClick={()=>***}>
        Move to Second page!</Button>
  )
}

const Second = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button size="lg" color="success" style={{margin:"50px"}} onClick={()=>***}>
        Move to Third page!!</Button>
  );
}
const Third = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>Third Page</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why you don t use react router to navigate between the pages?

Comment: I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979797/9098350). It's a react-native question, but the approach might be useful for this question as well. The idea is that you associate keys and components (pages) and conditionally render a component based on the current key value in state. If you want to change the state of a parent component inside a child you could pass the state update function (`setPageState`) to the child via props and call it from the child.

Comment: @Florin I don't want to permit user to access directly `Second` or `Third` page. My site is like questionnaire site Each page has Question1, Question2 or Question3, I want to let the user move according order.

Comment: @Bas van der Linden Thank you for your comment. `If you want to change the state of a parent component inside a child you could pass the state update function (setPageState) to the child via props and call it from the child. ` it might be helpful for may case. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to dedicate specific url to each page. So it can be easier to manage.
Below is my suggestion:

LandingPage.jsx

```
export default function LandingPage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        <Header></Header>    
        {props.children}
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    );
  
}
```

First.jsx

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"
const First = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory(); 
  return (
      <LandingPage>
        <Button size="lg" color="success" style={{margin:"50px"}} onClick={()=>history.push("/second")}>
        Move to Second page!</Button>
     </LandingPage>
  )
}
```

App.js

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import First from "./First"
import Second from "./Second"

function App() {
  return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Login} exact></Route>
              <Router path="/first" component={First}></Route>
              <Router path="/second" component={Second></Route>
            </Switch>
           </Router>
        )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is good idea to use specific url and nice suggestion for me. However I don't want user directory to `second`. My site is like questionnaire site Each page has Question1, Question2 or Question3.